# What would an appropriate suffix be to mean "branch of magic"

Tags: suffixes

I know "-mancy" already exists (like necromancy and pyromancy), but if you look into the root of the word, it acutally refers to divination, and not general magic powers

It could be easily argued that "-mancy" has taken on a new meaning in today's day, but something about it doesn't feel right

I've considered using "-ology", but that seems to be more for the study of a subject, rather than the practice (i.e. casting spells)

I could easily just come up with a gibberish word, but I was hoping to find something already in the English language, so it would sound more natural